# Having trouble parsing json in typescript/react due to types

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, types

I am making an api call and receiving the response. I would like to parse the response, as it is an array of objects. For example the json looks like this

```
{
    "totalSize": "56",
     "sortedKeys": [
        {
            "size": "12",
            "key": "test:key"
        },
        {
            "size": "13",
            "key": "completed"
        },
        {
            "size": "16",
            "key": "awaiting"
        }
        ]
"sortedPatterns": [
        {
            "pattern": "test:*",
            "count": 90,
            "size": "300"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "completed",
            "count": 2742,
            "size": "45"
        },
     ]
```

So I have three interfaces like this

```
interface SortedKeys {
    key:string;
    size:string;
};
interface SortedPatterns{
  count:string;
  pattern:string;
  size:string;
};
interface ApiResponseBody {
  sortedKey:SortedKeys[];
  sortedPattern:SortedPatterns[];
}
```

And I set a state like this

```
const [resData, setResData] =  useState<ApiResponseBody>({sortedKey:[],sortedPattern:[]});
```

After making a call....
`await setResData(body.pageData.sortedPatterns)`

I want to be able to access certain elements in the array of objects like being able to do `resData[0]` and that will give me the 0th index of the object. But I get this error:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'ApiResponseBody'.Property '0' does not exist on type 'ApiResponseBody'.`

I cant exactly figure out how to make a correct type to be able to properly parse this

Comment: You are trying to `setResData` to an array but the type of `useState<ApiResponseBody>` demands an element of that array.

Comment: That has nothing to do with *types*, your code won't work that way even in Javascript. You have an *object* with two arrays in it, which one do you want the first element of? Saying you want the zeroth element of the object doesn't make any sense...and the compiler is trying to tell you that.

Comment: thanks yes. I was confused on that @JaredSmith. I was thinking since I tried this await setResData(body.pageData.sortedPatterns) resData would have the array of objects for sortedPatterns and I could access it like resdata[0]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `resData` is not an array but an object of type `ApiResponseBody`. Therefore, it doesn't have numerical indices, which is why you are getting the TypeScript error.

If you want to access elements within `sortedKeys` or `sortedPatterns` arrays, you need to do so by referencing them directly:

- `resData.sortedKey[0]` to access the first element in `sortedKey`.
- `resData.sortedPattern[0]` to access the first element in `sortedPattern`.

Before using these, you might want to check if the arrays have any elements:

```js
if (resData.sortedKey.length > 0) {
  const firstSortedKey = resData.sortedKey[0];
  console.log(firstSortedKey);
}

if (resData.sortedPattern.length > 0) {
  const firstSortedPattern = resData.sortedPattern[0];
  console.log(firstSortedPattern);
}
```

Additionally, you have some inconsistencies between your JSON response and your TypeScript interfaces. In your interfaces, you named the properties `sortedKey` and `sortedPattern` but in the JSON, they are `sortedKeys` and `sortedPatterns`. Make sure these names match.

Here is how you could correct your interfaces:

```js
interface SortedKeys {
    key: string;
    size: string;
}

interface SortedPatterns {
    count: string;
    pattern: string;
    size: string;
}

interface ApiResponseBody {
    sortedKeys: SortedKeys[];
    sortedPatterns: SortedPatterns[];
}

// Initialize the state
const [resData, setResData] = useState<ApiResponseBody>({ sortedKeys: [], sortedPatterns: [] });

// Setting state after API call
// make sure `body.pageData` actually contains both `sortedKeys` and `sortedPatterns`
setResData({ sortedKeys: body.pageData.sortedKeys, sortedPatterns: body.pageData.sortedPatterns });
```

Make sure your API response and TypeScript definitions are consistent with each other.

Comment: @tankman07 you welcome, you can mark it as your accepted answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Let's take react out of this and look at the data.

You basically have this:

```
const resData = {
  totalSize: '56',
  sortedKeys: [
    //...
  ],
  sortedPatterns: [
    //...
  ],
}

resData[0]
// ^ Property '0' does not exist on type '{ totalSize: string; sortedKeys: { size: string; key: string; }[]; sortedPatterns: { pattern: string; count: number; size: string; }[]; }'.(7053)
```

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgEQIZVTAvDA3gKBhihAwBsBlASwC8EAuGAcgFYA2JgGkJghDigIAJgGkEATwiMA2jyIEii3rQbMAjACYucxQGsJjJoOj1947UoC+3JQqXK6htQGYL9s4dABbAA5kEgkJuRNY6dkoQKk4cNu4GzKgA7qhUUFRgAObBMKFEALqxfALCAArognCQMmE6RD7lCJWGxlD0AFTZRKAArmCtMACcAAyxEVHMzkND2bmK4Yr1UBVgniC+-oGdMD19jBoA7AAsGqOKkY7MhywzsQX4lviPiCjoqNJDeTAA9F8wjXD8IA)

---

The problem here is that `resData` is not an array. It is an object. So you can't treat that root object like an array.

If you want array data you have to drill into it:

```
resData.sortedKeys[0] // fine
resData.sortedPatterns[0] // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgEQIZVTAvDA3gKBhihAwBsBlASwC8EAuGAcgFYA2JgGkJghDigIAJgGkEATwiMA2jyIEii3rQbMAjACYucxQGsJjJoOj1947UoC+3JQqXK6htQGYL9s4dABbAA5kEgkJuRNY6dkoQKk4cNu4GzKgA7qhUUFRgAObBMKFEALqxfALCAArognCQMmE6RD7lCJWGxlD0AFTZRKAArmCtMACcAAyxEVHMzkND2bmK4Yr1UBVgniC+-oGdMD19jBoA7AAsGqOKkY7MhywzsQX4lviPiCjoqNJDeTAA9F8wjXD8fDPNAYAB0RUCYkk70+PxgADN0gggUgQahwfxAmUlo1IDDvr9EWAEEA)

---

Now your react `useState` will also work fine:

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUM-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)

Comment: Thanks, In my code I set resData to be await setResData(body.pageData.sortedPatterns) so I was thinking that resData would be set to have the array of sortedPatterns.

Comment: Ahh, well in that case you se the type of `useState` wrong in `useState<ApiResponseBody>`. That should have been `useState<ApiResponseBody['sortedPatterns']>(...)` if you want to do that.